# Prevent numpy select from casting values in the "choicelist" and "default" argument

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a list of boolean pandas Series (all of the same length), and a list of values of the same length as the list of Series. I'm trying to apply numpy's select function using `np.NaN` as a default value to create a new Series from the result using `np.NaN` for rows that didn't fulfill any of the conditions. Here's what the line by itself looks like:

```py
result = pd.Series(np.select(list_of_conditions, list_of_values, default=np.NaN))
```

The issue I'm having is that it looks at some point during the process all the values **including** `np.NaN` get casted to string if a single one of them is a string.
Here's a minimal reproducible example:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

series1 = pd.Series([True, False, False])
series2 = pd.Series([True, True, False])
list_of_series = [series1, series2]
list_of_values = ['1', '2']

result = pd.Series(np.select(list_of_series, list_of_values, default=np.NaN))

print(result.unique())
# Printed result --> ['1' '2' 'nan']
# Desired result --> ['1' '2' nan]
```

I tried (to no avail) to replace `list_of_values` with numpy array with `object` dtype:

```py
# [...]
list_of_values = np.array(['1', 2], dtype=object)
# here I'm putting 2 instead of '2' to show that
# even items from the array get casted to string, not just the `default` argument

print(list_of_values)
# Printed result --> ['1' 2], as expected

result = pd.Series(np.select(list_of_series, list_of_values, default=np.NaN))

print(result.unique())
# Printed result --> ['1' '2' 'nan'] nope
```

`select` has no dtype argument, so I don't know what to do, aside from botching a solution by replacing all `'nan'` strings with actual `nan`s, which irks me. Do I have to reimplement my own version of numpy's select or did I miss something somewhere ?

**Edit**: I'm using numpy version 1.21.3, and pandas version 1.3.4.

Comment: Can you examine the `np.select` output before putting it  in `pd.Series`?

Comment: `pd.Series` isn't the problem, it's already been converted to string before converting the result to a series. I kept the conversion just so my example actually matches the goal I described.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cast the default to `'object'`:

```
result = pd.Series(np.select(list_of_series, list_of_values, default=np.array(np.NaN, dtype='object')))
```

Result of `print(result.unique())`:

```
['1' '2' nan]
```

This is because the resulting dtype is [created](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/54c52f13713f3d21795926ca4dbb27e16fada171/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L830) using [`result_type`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.result_type.html) from the types of the choice list and the default: `np.result_type('U1', float)` yields `'<U32'` whereas `np.result_type('U1', np.dtype('object'))` yields `'O'`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't expect that solution!

Answer (score 1):

If you do not mind, another option is [case_when](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.case_when.case_when) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/); it is a wrapper around `pd.Series.mask` and as much as possible passes all the hardwork of dtypes and the like to Pandas:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

df = pd.DataFrame({'col':series1})
# case_when is an alternation 
# of conditions and expected values
(df
.case_when(series1, '1', # condition, value
           series2, '2', 
           np.nan, # default
           column_name = 'result')
)

     col result
0   True      1
1  False      2
2  False    NaN
```

If however, you stick to pure numpy, then @Stef's solution is spot on.